# Upgrading ruby on a production server with Rails and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger

I have a few Rails apps, each running on their own server. They run under Passenger-apache, and currently under ruby 1.9.3.  Currently, they run under a ruby installed and managed with rbenv.

I'd like to upgrade them all to ruby 2.2.x.  As long as I'm doing this, I'd like to upgrade them from passenger 4.x to 5.x as well.

Let's assume I've tested them all on my development box and am confident they run fine under ruby 2.2.

As I think through this, I get very confused about the best way to do this -- especially with minimal production downtime.

I guess I'd start out by installing ruby 2.2 under rbenv, which theoretically shouldn't disturb the running apps. Passenger is installed under a particular ruby, but then has the option of running apps under different rubies. Should I install the latest passenger first, under the new ruby 2.2, but configured to run the existing apps under the old ruby?  And then upgrading the apps to the new ruby... I guess involves running `bundle install` again, to get all dependencies installed under the new ruby?

Or something else entirely? Is there a way to do this that is relatively safe, and will have limited or zero downtime for my apps?

Has anyone done this before? I'm fairly familiar with all the pieces already, and can brainstorm possible approaches myself, but when I start, there are too many places where I'm not sure what the best approach is.  What I could really use is advice from someone who has already done this, or is otherwise pretty sure that what they recommend will work as they say -- not just guesses about things you haven't done that might work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your applications work under the new ruby version. I have had some legacy Rails 3.2.x applications that works up to ruby 2.1.5, but breaks in ruby 2.2.x. You should be fine with updating your ruby and passenger versions.

Since each application runs on their own server, you don't have to really worry about running multiple versions of `passenger`. You should be able to install the new version ruby on each server, install the gems, update apache to the newer passenger and restart apache to have everything take effect. Worst case, you can clone your servers to a virtual environment and test everything prior to doing it on production. This would help you minimize downtime as you would have any workarounds and/or research of bugs done prior to touching the production environment.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should have said that, and I'll add it, let's assume I've tested and know my apps work. My question is about exactly what steps I need to take, in what order, to upgrade everything, with zero or minimal downtime. I think maybe you've answered it, but I'm still a bit confused, would you mind changing it to a 1,2,3 step-by-step?

Comment: ideally with some details about how each step is accomplished too?